# How to aggregate among the values of different tables in a single query?

Tags: sql, join, sum, subquery

[Tables Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bguUD.png)

These are my datas from 3 tables.

```
select*from ShippingDetails 
ProductCode   Shipping Quantity
 MFD01-10            50 
 MFD01-07            50  
 MFD01-10            10 

select*from ProductDetails
 ProductCode   Shipping Quantity
   MFD01-07          500
   MFD01-10          100
   MFD01-07         1000
   MSD01-21          200                   

  select*from StockData
  ProductCode     UrunAdi ( " Product Name")
  MFD01-07        7  mm FTube       
  MFD01-10        10 mm FTube       
  MSD01-21        21 mm STube   
  MSD01-27        27 mm STube
```

I try to write these two queries but it didnt work. I couldn't merge as one table.

```
  select StockData.ProductCode,SUM( ProductDetails.ProductQuantity) as ' Product Quantity' from ProductDetails RIGHT OUTER JOIN StockData on ProductDetails.ProductCode=StockData.ProductCode group by StockData.ProductCode



 Product Code     Product Quantity
 MFD01-07               1500
 MFD01-10               100   
 MSD01-21               200
 MSD01-27               NULL

 select StockData.ProductCode, SUM ( ShippingDetails.ShippingQuantity) as ' Shipping Quantity' from ShippingDetails RIGHT OUTER JOIN StockData on ShippingDetails.ProductCode=StockData.ProductCode group by StockData.ProductCode
Product Code     Shipping Quantity
 MFD01-07               50
 MFD01-10               60  
 MSD01-21               NULL
 MSD01-27               NULL
```

**This result that i need.** Which query would give it? I will appreciate if you solve my issue.

```
 Product Code     (Product-Shipping) Quantity
 MFD01-07               1450
 MFD01-10               40  
 MSD01-21               200
 MSD01-27               NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a subquery for each table and then join together to calculate the total.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c37f/8)**

```
SELECT SD.[ProductCode],
       COALESCE(PD.stock, 0) - COALESCE(D.sales, 0)  as [(Product-Shipping) Quantity]
FROM StockData SD    
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [ProductCode], SUM([Product Quantity]) stock
           FROM ProductDetails
           GROUP BY [ProductCode]) PD
       ON SD.[ProductCode] = PD.[ProductCode]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [ProductCode], SUM([Shipping Quantity]) sales
           FROM ShippingDetails
           GROUP BY [ProductCode]) D
       ON SD.[ProductCode] = D.[ProductCode]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ProductCode | (Product-Shipping) Quantity |
|-------------|-----------------------------|
|    MFD01-07 |                        1450 |
|    MFD01-10 |                          40 |
|    MSD01-21 |                         200 |
|    MSD01-27 |                           0 |
```

Comment: `SELECT StockData.ProductCode, COALESCE (ProductDetails.ProductQuantity,0) - COALESCE (ShippingDetails.ShippingQuantity,0) as 'RESULT'  
FROM StockData
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ProductDetails.ProductCode, SUM(ProductDetails.ProductQuantity) FROM ProductDetails GROUP BY  ProductDetails.ProductCode) 
ON StockData.ProductCode=ProductDetails.ProductCode
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ShippingDetails.ProductCode, SUM(ShippingDetails.ShippingQuantity) FROM ShippingDetails GROUP BY ShippingDetails.ProductCode)
ON StockData.ProductCode=ShippingDetails.ProductCode`                        It didnt work

Comment: Please check the sql fiddle demo

Comment: In your query you didnt create alias for `SUM(ProductDetails.ProductQuantity)`